# Implementing slide transition after a option item selected android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I build a action bar.Which contain a item say setting (image).After clicking on the image the another activity is being started.
But I want the starting activity to show sliding transition effect.current activity slide left and hide and starting activity should slide from right to left.

here is code

code for selecting the item

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.setting:
            goToSetting();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

gotoSetting function :

```
public void goToSetting() {
    // Do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageSetting.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

which is calling activity named "DisplayMessageSetting"

please help

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `onCreate` method in your `DisplayMessageSetting` activity like this :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //specify the animation
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left_in, 0);
    //...
}
```

Create a `slide_left_in.xml` file in your `res/anim` folder (create the folder if it doesn't exist) and paste the following :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="400"/>
 </set>
```

This way you just specified an animation set with one translate animation in it.
You have a lot more options to tweak that animation, you can learn a bit more about that [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html).

Comment: how to specify the animation I mean to say R.anim.slide_left_in